# How to use Walmart API with Custom URL

Tags: walmart-api

This is a mystery. I am looking thru the Walmart API docs and I'm not seeing a way to create these personalized products.

A "normal" product looks like this:

`https://www.walmart.com/ip/Russell-Exclusive-Men-s-Retro-Track-Pant/blahblahblah`

All contained within the parent `walmart` URL.

However when it comes to personalized products, somehow a custom sub-domain is generated. It looks like this:

`http://personalizeditems-cps.walmart.com/685770978`

or this:

`https://personalizedgifts.walmart.com/t/index.php?sku=GC777`

Does anyone know where that is coming from? Or how these products were created on a seemingly custom sub-domain but still within the Walmart Marketplace?

Thanks

Comment: have you managed to make any progress on this? Do you know anything about the mysterious "add to cart" API or how to test the entire setup, for example? I'm an approved vendor but I'm really struggling to gather all the technical info I need for the integration. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

It is a rather different setup I have to agree.

However, the way Walmart sets up Third Party Personalized items is by having the third party setup a page using the third parties host.

The Third Party then makes a request to Walmart for the header and footer portion of the page all while keeping the personalized information in the middle.  Walmart then uses the third party page and just forwards the URL to their site.

[Set Up Personalized Items - documentation](https://supplierhelp.walmart.com/s/guide?article=000005156)

#### Big Things To Remember

- You are responsible for the hosting.
- You have to ensure the Header and Footer

  - Always load
  - Are not blocked via page styling

Really That is about it

I recently discovered all of this when I started the process to create a personalized page for a client.  I am currently setting up their API portion.  Just finished the frontend of all of this so all should be up to date.  I wish you the best!  =)

Comment: I'm also trying to integrate a personalization page with Walmart. Unfortunately the docs are very incomplete. For example there is nothing on the  "add to cart" API or how to sandbox/test the entire setup. Walmart support have been... less then helpful. Have you managed to make any progress on this? Would greatly appreciate some technical details here.